# Differences between Assert.True and Assert.IsTrue in NUnit?

Tags: nunit, assert

Is there any differences between those two?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No difference. `Assert.True()` and others (without `Is`) were added since v2.5.

From documentation for the version `2.5`: ([nunit v2.5](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.5))

> Two forms are provided for the True, False, Null and NotNull
>   conditions. The "Is" forms are compatible with earlier versions of the
>   NUnit framework, while those without "Is" are provided for
>   compatibility with NUnitLite

BTW, Disassembled nunit.framework.dll (using ILSPY)

```cs
public static void IsTrue(bool condition)
{
    Assert.That(condition, Is.True, null, null);
}

public static void True(bool condition)
{
    Assert.That(condition, Is.True, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Do users have any preference for which to use? Or is there one that "should" be used?

Comment: According to the next answer, the three implementations are exactly the same and all rely on Assert.That()  

So the best would be to directly use Assert.That()... 

sll's answer (here, in this post) is copied from the NUnit site: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.5 on the bottom of the page. 

Other than THAT, and in any case try to avoid all three and use better assertions, as Eyal Eini (Ayende) from RavenDB wrote here: http://ayende.com/blog/4118/assert-true-is-the-tool-of-last-resort

Answer (score 15):

There does not seem to be any implementational difference. Looking at the source code for the most recent version [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nunit-core/nunitv2/2.6.1/view/head:/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Assert.cs), the `True`, `IsTrue` and `That` are all implemented in the same way when the argument lists are the same:

```cs
public static void True(bool condition, string message, params object[] args)
{
    Assert.That(condition, Is.True, message, args);
}
...
public static void IsTrue(bool condition, string message, params object[] args)
{
    Assert.That(condition, Is.True, message, args);
}
...
static public void That(bool condition, string message, params object[] args)
{
    Assert.That(condition, Is.True, message, args);
}
```

The overloaded methods are implemented analogously.